# Как реализовать календарь, на несколько дней начиная с текущего?

Tags: javascript, html, календарь

Для каждого дня должна отображаться неделя и месяц (прилагаю скрин) Готовых плагинов не нашел, какие еще возможны решения?
[image: календарь одним рядом]

Comment: Написать самостоятельно, какие тут ещё решения могут быть 

Answer (score 1):

Для такой тривиальной задачи не нужны никакие плагины, а достаточно лишь внимательно прочитать и постараться понять, что из себя представляет объект [Date](https://learn.javascript.ru/date) и способы его [форматирования](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat).

```js
let elWeek = document.querySelector('.week');
let dNow = new Date();
let dOpt = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('ru-RU', { weekday: 'short', month: 'long', day: 'numeric' });
for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
  let dNew = dOpt.formatToParts(dNow);
  elWeek.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `
    <div class="day">
      <span>${dNew[0].value}</span>
      <span>${dNew[2].value}</span>
      <span>${dNew[4].value}</span>
    </div>
  `);
  dNow.setDate(dNow.getDate() + 1);
}
```

```css
h2 {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.week {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 10px;
  height: 100px;
}
.week::before,
.week::after {
  content: "";
  flex: 1;
  height: 1px;
  background-color: #8e8775;
}

.day {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 5px;
  height: 80px; width: 80px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #8e8775;
  transition: 0.3s ease;
}

.day > span:nth-of-type(1) { color: #633b00; font: italic 10px/1em sans-serif; }
.day > span:nth-of-type(2) { color: #000; font: bold 20px/1em sans-serif; }
.day > span:nth-of-type(3) { color: #000; font: 14px/1em sans-serif; }
.day:hover { background-color: #633b00; }
.day:hover > span { color: #fff; }
```

```html
<h2>Запись на просмотр</h2>
<div class="week"></div>
```